# Arabic and English combination recrod retrieval from oracle java

Tags: java, oracle

In my master database I have Arabic or Arabic English combination data. Now while reading the Arbic data only it's working fine but for Arabic English combination I am getting different behaviors.

In java it should be display Value stored in the database.

CHARACTER SET in Database - AR8ISO8859P6.

Value stored in the database or can be fetched from PL/SQL Developer-
[image: Value stored in the database]

Value I am getting from java or Toad developer -[image]

Comment: There might be hidden formatting characters affecting how it is *printed*. Print out the characters of the string in hex form, e.g. using `str.codePoints().forEach(c -> System.out.printf("%x ", c));`. Show us the result in the question.

Comment: If you e.g. have `str = "MYTEST لحضور 256"` (aka `str = "MYTEST \u0644\u062D\u0636\u0648\u0631 256"`), then it prints `4d 59 54 45 53 54 20 644 62d 636 648 631 20 32 35 36`. As you can see, the Arabic characters are in the middle of the string, but they show at the end of the string in that string literal (at least for me). I believe that is a result of mixing left-to-right and right-to-left characters in the same string, but I'm not sure about that, since I don't know anything about right-to-left scripts.

Comment: So, what could be the probable solution for the same? As I have this requirement.

Comment: My first two comments is intended for you to figure out if this is a problem with the string read from the database, or a problem with how the string is *printed*. With the example string from my second comment, if it prints the Arabic characters at the end, then it is a printing problem. As I said, I don't know anything about mixing left-to-right and right-to-left characters, so I cannot help with that, but it could actually be that it is PL/SQL Developer that shows the text in the wrong order. Think about that, before you try to force a fix in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Both values you see are correct. They just have a different "base direction" which is set by the software that displays the text.

If the base direction is left to right, "english arabic" is rendered as "english cibara". If the base direction is right to left, "english arabic" is rendered as "cibara english". Both renderings are valid, and which one should be used depends on the context.

You can read more about the bidirectional text layout algorithm at https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics

Comment: So how to read the value as per the image mentioned in "Value stored in the database or can be fetched from PL/SQL Developer" from java and toad.

Comment: You are reading the same value. It's just not displayed the same way. And, unless you're a developer working for Toad, you probably can't change how Toad chooses to display strings. Why do you care about how Toad displays it, if you can display it the way you want in your own app?

Comment: I am using it in Java display. So, in java after reading the same I am displaying it to PDF with XSLT

Comment: If the text is not being rendered the way you expect in the resulting PDF, post another question and include the details of how you're generating that PDF - which libraries you're using and so on. It would also help to know if "MYTEST" is the first or last word of string, and which of the two directions you consider correct